# Visual Studio Code Snippet - Change Literal Name?

Tags: visual-studio, code-snippets

I am trying to create a snippet that creates a field and a property for that field.
I want to use pascalCase for the field and CamelCase for the property, I want the snippet to do this automatically. I can do it if I create two different literals and manually write the name for the field and the name for the property, is there a way to automatically "create" the name for the property with capital first letter with the name taken from the name of the field?

This is my current snippet code:

```
<CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
<Header>
  <Title>Property etc</Title>
  <Shortcut>fprop</Shortcut>
</Header>
<Snippet>
  <Declarations>
    <Literal>
      <ID>type</ID>
      <Default>int</Default>
    </Literal>
    <Literal>
      <ID>name</ID>
      <Default>propertyName</Default>
    </Literal>
  </Declarations>
  <Code Language="csharp">
    <![CDATA[private $type$ $name$;

    public $type$ $name$    <<<<--- this $name$ must have its first letter capitalized in the final result
    { 
        get 
        {
            return this.$name$;
        } 
        set 
        {
            this.$name$ = value;
        } 
    }
    $end$]]>
  </Code>
</Snippet>
```

This is the expected result:

```
private int propertyName;

public int PropertyName
{
    get         
    {
        return this.propertyName;
    }
    set
    {
        this.propertyName = value;
    }
}
```

If I use a different name for the field, for example "someFieldName" the name for the property should automatically become SomeFieldName (at the time of the snippet creation of course)

I know that I can do this if I use two separate Literals, but then I have to manually write the name for the field and then write the name for the property aswell, I want to avoid writing the property name manually.

Comment: I don't think the input can be altered in the visual studio code at the moment. You can raise this as an issue (a new feature) and wait what they respond about it.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with ReSharper.
Using `Template Explorer` ("`Extensions->ReSharper->Tools->Templates Explorer...`")

create new template

```
private $TYPE$ $FIELD_NAME$;
public $TYPE$ $PROPERTY_NAME$
{
    get
    {
        return this.$FIELD_NAME$;
    }
    set
    {
        this.$FIELD_NAME$ = value;
    }
}
```

Template settings:

- uncheck `Reformat`

Parameters settings:

- `PROPERTY_Name` set as first element, `Editable`, `Suggest name for a variable`
- `TYPE` set as second element, `MO-2`, `Suggest type for a new variable`
- `FIELD_NAME` set as third element, `Not Editable`, `Value of another variable with first character in lower case` and select `PROPERTY_NAME`